# Sum Components as String

Tags: python, vector

This is a very simple question I have. I'd like to create a function that sums the components two vectors. Here's what I wrote:

```
def sumadevectores(x, y):
    return [x[i] + y[i] for i in range(len(x))]
```

It works fine. But let's say I have two vectors `x = (a, b)` and `y = (c, d)`. Their sum is `(a + c, b + d)`. Since `a, b, c` and `d` are not defined I can't use my function.

What can I do? I was thinking about converting the components to string and sum their values but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. What do you mean by "since `a, b, c` and `d` are not defined I can't use my function"? What type of values are represented by these variables (integers, strings, etc.)?

Comment: what's your more general problem you try to achieve? given the bigger picture and the usecase it would be easier to help.

Comment: Your function works correctly. If you call it with undefined input, it will, obviously, fail.

Comment: if you literally have `x = (a, b) and y = (c, d)` , have you initialized `a, b, c and d` somewhere ? like `a = 5`...

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following(if len(x) == len(y)):

```
def sumadevectores(x, y):
    z = list(zip(x, y))
    return tuple([sum(i) for i in z])
```

If you did not understand please ask